# Get data using angularJS

Tags: php, arrays, json, angularjs

I have an array

```
[
    {
        "Bookmarked":false,
        "CategoryID":26,
        "CreatedBy_Profile": {
            "ID":68,"Name":"René Bang Hansen",
            "Picture": { 
                "MD5HASH":"ILBZ0Zo7cWHlN3wASB9LHg==",
                "URI":"https:\/\/cetest5.blob.core.windows.net\/images\/23166e0c-1441-47b6-ad83-f66f9d540c89"
            }
         },
         "Created_Timestamp": "2015-09-16T10:55:27.2270000","Current_Location":""
    }
]
```

How can I get URI of Picture.
I am getting CategoryID by using this code.

```
<ul ng-repeat="cat in catadata">
    <li>            
        {{cat.CategoryID}} 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: have you tried {{cat.CreatedBy_Profile.URI}}

Answer (score 2):

I believe following code will help you to get picture uri -

`{{cat.CreatedBy_Profile.Picture.URI}}`